# Padding on span overlaping on other elements

Tags: html, css

Assuming this html/css code:

```css
tr, td {
  border: solid 1px black;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
#x {
  border: solid 1px black;
  padding: 10px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>Y</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<span id="x">
  totosss
</span>
```

Why the green span is overlapping on the table and how to avoid this behavior ?

Comment: span is inline. it will check for text position and then move out. If you dont want it to overlap, a non-inline element, such as block or inline-block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the padding in inline elements is not like line-height. If you change the inline element to an inline-block or block element it works as you expected

```css
tr, td {
  border: solid 1px black;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
#x {
  border: solid 1px black;
  padding: 10px;
  background: green; 
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>Y</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<span id="x">
  totosss
</span>
```